# Proving Lagrange remainder converges

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find the power series for $f(x)=\frac{1}{a+x}$ around $x_0 \neq -a$

I found by induction that $f^{(n)}=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{(a+x)^{n+1}}$

And therefore the Lagrange remainder is $(-1)^{n+1} (\frac{x-x_0}{a+ \xi })^{n+1} $ and i need to show it converges to $0$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$ around $x_0$, but i'm not sure how to justify that. I think I can say $x-x_0$ is "as small as i want" so assuming $a \neq 0$ this is almost enough, but how do i know $\xi$ doesn't screw it up?

Answer (score 1):

Proving it is equivalence to proving Taylor theorem itself: difference between function and Taylor multinomial  equals Lagrange remainder. That $\xi$ doesn't screw it up comes from difference converge to zero.